# $_FILES["file"]["name"] is returning empty value

Tags: php, html, file, upload

Alright, so I'm creating this website that allows users to upload files directly to the server with no logins. Everything works great (so far), except for one small issue. When I log IP's, I want it to print the users IP and the file name they've uploaded. Everything works besides the file name. I've checked every possible issue and searched for hours upon hours. Everything it could have been has not made it work. Please take a look at what I have and let me know if you find the issue. Thanks!

If you're curious, the website is http://box.endurehosting.com/

```
<html>

<head>

<title>EndureBox | Upload</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

 <style type="text/css">

@import url("webfonts/Muli/fontstylesheet.css");

/*<![CDATA[*/

        .TitleText 
            {
                font-family: Muli;
                font-size: 58px;
                font-style: normal;
                line-height: normal;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-variant: normal;
                color: #FFF;
                text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #707070;
            }

        .NormalText 
            {
                font-family: Muli;
                font-size: 18px;
                font-style: normal;
                line-height: normal;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-variant: normal;
                color: #FFF;
                text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #999;
            }

        .SuccessText 
            {
                font-family: Muli;
                font-size: 30px;
                font-style: normal;
                line-height: normal;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-variant: normal;
                color: #83F52C;
                text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #83F52C;
            }

        .FailedText     
            {
                font-family: Muli;
                font-size: 30px;
                font-style: normal;
                line-height: normal;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-variant: normal;
                color: #FF0000;
                text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #FF0000;
            }

        .FileText 
            {
                font-family: Muli;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-style: normal;
                line-height: normal;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-variant: normal;
                color: #FFF;
                text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #999;
            }

        .BlackText 
            {
                font-family: Muli;
                font-size: 19px;
                font-style: normal;
                line-height: normal;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-variant: normal;
                color: #000000;
                text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #999999;
            }

    /*]]>*/

body {background-image:url("images/background.png");}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div align="center">

</br><h1 class="TitleText">Endure Box</h1>

<?php 
if ($_POST)
    {
        $folder = "box/"; 
        $redirect = "index.php?complete";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "$folder" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        header('Location: '.$redirect);
    }

if (isset($_GET['complete'])) 
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                echo "<span class='notice'><p class='SuccessText'>Upload Failed!</p></span>";
                echo "<span class='notice'><p class='NormalText'>" . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "</p></span>";
            }
        else
            {
                echo "<span class='notice'><p class='SuccessText'>Upload Successful!</p></span>";

                $ipLog="log.txt";
                $friendly_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                $register_globals = (bool) ini_get('register_gobals'); 

                if ($register_globals)
                {
                    $ip = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR); 
                }
                else 
                {
                    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                }           

                $date=date ("l dS of F Y h:i:s A");
                $log=fopen("$ipLog", "a+"); 

                if (preg_match("/\bhtm\b/i", $ipLog) || preg_match("/\bhtml\b/i", $ipLog))  
                    { 
                        fputs($log, "File: $friendly_name | IP Address: $ip | Date Uploaded: $date <br>"); 
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        fputs($log, "File: $friendly_name | IP Address: $ip | Date Uploaded: $date \n"); 
                    }

                fclose($log);
        }
    }
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p class="NormalText">Choose a file to upload</p></br>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="FileText"/></br></br></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="BlackText" value="Submit"/></br></br></br>

</form>

<a href="contents.php"> <img border="0" src="/images/box.png" alt="Open Box" width="200" height="200"></a></br></br></br>

<a href="contents.php" class="NormalText">Open Box</a>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where does it not work? After the `POST` or the `GET`? The `POST` should give you the file, the `GET` won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the problem is the following line:

```
header('Location: '.$redirect);
```

When you first run `move_uploaded_file` and then make redirection using `header` function, `$_FILES` array gets empty, so in next line simple you cannot check `$_FILES` anymore.

In addition I don't see any point making this redirectrion. When you `move_uploaded_file` it simple return true on success so you could change the following code:

```
<?php 
if ($_POST)
    {
        $folder = "box/"; 
        $redirect = "index.php?complete";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "$folder" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        header('Location: '.$redirect);
    }

if (isset($_GET['complete']))
```

into

```
<?php 

$uploadStatus = false;
if ($_POST)
    {
        $folder = "box/"; 

       $uploadStatus = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "$folder" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    }

if ($uploadStatus)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You're awesome! I've been trying to figure this out for the longest time!